# Insert user defined datatype into SQLite Database using python function

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So I want my database to contain the datatype `Item` I defined in python:

```
class Item:
  Name = str
  L = Location #An Array
  Quantity = int
  Description = str
```

I made a table with that as a datatype, the GUI that I use says that column is the `Item` type:

```
def CreateTable(DatabaseName ,TableName):
    conn = s.connect(DatabaseName)
    print ("Opened database successfully")
    conn.execute('CREATE TABLE ' + TableName + ' (id integer, Items Item);')
    print ("Table created successfully") 
    conn.close()
```

Now that I have that I want to insert values, so I defined the following function:

```
def AddItemToTable(DatabaseName, TableName, Items):
  conn = s.connect(DatabaseName)
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute('INSERT INTO '+TableName + '(id, Items) \
  VALUES(1,'+Items+')')
  conn.commit
  conn.close()
```

I execute these functions:

```
I = Item
CreateTable('HelloWorld.db', 'again1')
AddItemToTable('HelloWorld.db', 'again1', 'I')
```

The Database is made, the Table is made, it has the two columns, each column has the right type, but it says theres no column I. If I leave I out of quotes, it tells me it requires an `str` not type.

Comment: Did you try `django models`

Comment: Is there an *Item* type in SQLite? [Docs](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) do not indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Item* is actually a text type, you need to enclose values with quotes. And for that reason, use double quotes for the SQL string and single quotes for string literals.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO "+TableName+" (id, Items) VALUES (1,'"+Items+"')")
```

But actually the better way is to pass the value as a parameter which you do so as the second argument in [`cursor.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html) with no worrying about quote enclosure:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO "+TableName+" (id, Items) VALUES (1, ?)", Items)
```

Comment: I dont think it is a text type. I want to pass in the Item datatype I created. Is that not possible with a database?

Comment: Please look at link in my above comment. Where is the *Item* data type in SQLite 3? Also why are you passing a string into that function, then? What is `'I'`?